# listpicker WPtoolkit on WP8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm working on a small WP8 application
I have a xaml page in which I need to use a combobox/Listpicker.
I've installed the Windows Phone toolkit nuget package and i'm now using the ListPicker

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Grid.Column="0">
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="toto2" />
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="toto1" />
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="toto3" />
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="toto4" />
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="toto5" />
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="toto6" />
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="toto7" />
  <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="toto2" />
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Problem is :

I can see the list my list picker, but it doesn't behave like the wpf ComboBox 
[(here is exactlly what I am seing)](http://lnimong.tumblr.com/image/89081941939)
I can only the first element, and when I tap it, it doesn't display the rest of the list.
This migth be easy, but I could use some help here.

Do anyone know what I am doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used system.String instead of ListPickerItem and it work better :

> ```
>     <toolkit:ListPicker Header="Background">
>         <sys:String>dark</sys:String>
>         <sys:String>light</sys:String>
>         <sys:String>dazzle</sys:String>
>     </toolkit:ListPicker>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess...

It's not because you have a duplicate item of

```
<toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="toto2" />
```

both top and bottom of the list?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem, and I hope my solution can be helpful. In my example the data is bound  to the ListPicker in the `page contructor`.

```
BloodTypesLp.ItemsSource = ApplicationState.BloodTypes; // blood types is of type String []
```

The xaml code:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Grid.Row="1"
         x:Name="BloodTypesLp" 
         BorderBrush="DarkGray"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         BorderThickness="3"
         Margin="25,0,25,0"
         SelectionChanged="bloodTypesLP_SelectionChanged"
         ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed"
         Foreground="Black"
         FontSize="30">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="LPDataTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="40"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

The `<toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>` is here to describe, what happens when the ListPicker is tapped and will expand.

End result:

[image]

And When you `tap` the list picker:

[image]

Comment: I tryed the following :